# Rails and prawn: trim pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, prawn

Say I've got a three-page PDF and I want to trim the first page. I'm using prawn to manage the PDFs. How would be best to go about that? I think I've got the logic alright but I can't seem to implement it.

```
filename = "pdf/three_pages.pdf"
Prawn::Document.generate("two_pages.pdf", :template => filename(page.next?)) do
  send_file ...
end
```

I need to implement a next/skip page function into the template. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written possibly the worst method to trim the first page of a PDF with prawn. Maybe it'll help you.

```
def trim_the_first_page_badly
  temp_file = "#{::Rails.root}/public/temporary/fat_#{@document.temp_file_name}.pdf"
  new_temp_file = "#{::Rails.root}/public/temporary/#{@document.temp_file_name}.pdf"
  page_total = 0
  prawn_pdf = Prawn::Document.generate(temp_file, :margin => 0, :page_size => "A4", :skip_page_creation => true) do |fat|
    @document.process(fat)
    fat.render
    page_total = fat.page_count-1
  end
  new_prawn_pdf = Prawn::Document.generate(new_temp_file, :skip_page_creation => true) do |thin|
    page_total.times { |i| thin.start_new_page(:template => temp_file, :template_page => i+2) }
    send_data thin.render, :filename => "#{@document.temp_file_name}", :type => "application/pdf"
  end
end
```

No guarantees but it works for me.